# What Quantitative Evaluation Methods Should Be Used for Robotics Simulation Research by ros2?

Tags: ros2, turtlebot

I am part of a research team working on robotics, and we're currently exploring the creation and evaluation of photorealistic 3D virtual environments for robot manipulation and navigation tasks. Our methodology combines Neural Radiance Fields (NeRF) with Unreal Engine 5 (UE5), aiming to create a seamless transition between simulated training environments and real-world applications in robotics.

Our project has achieved the following:

1. Utilization of NeRF for rendering and static geometry derived from indoor scene videos, to create realistic simulation environments for robots.
2. A faster approach to generating photorealistic 3D models of real-world interiors compared to existing methods.
3. Development of a visual guidance control policy with high fidelity, demonstrating effective simulation-to-reality transfer.

We are now at a crucial phase where we need to conduct quantitative evaluations of our work. Specifically, we're interested in methods that can measure and compare:

- The fidelity and accuracy of our 3D environments against actual real-world settings.
- The effectiveness of our control policies in transferring from simulation to reality.

Could anyone in the ROS community suggest ROS2-based libraries, tools, or methods that could assist in these quantitative evaluations? We're particularly interested in ROS2 capabilities that can aid in validating our simulation environments and control policies. References to similar studies or projects within the ROS ecosystem would also be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your guidance and insights.

Best regards,